# What fraction of heat is exchanged by thermal radiation (by ordinary objects)?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

I understand that heat can be transferred by conduction, convection and thermal radiation.

So, lets say when I bring a cold glass of milk in a room at room temperature, then what fraction of heat is transferred to the milk by radiation and what fraction by conduction?

(I guess that the heat exchange by thermal radiation would be very low)

Comment: For two ideal absorber/emitters, such a warm blackbody emitter in a closed refrigerator, the radiation calculation is straightforward. But I haven’t done it, and the comparison to conductive and convective cooling is interesting.

Comment: This is a straightforward homework-like question. Identify the constitutive equations for each mechanism (thousands of descriptions online and clearly explained in any introductory heat transfer text) and do the calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Heat transfer via radiation scales like the fourth power of the temperature in degrees absolute. It is very small for objects near room temperature like your glass of milk but climbs rapidly as you go above room temperature. at a couple hundred degrees above room temperature it is significant (think: hot stove) and a few hundred above that, it is dominant (think: glowing furnace). The guys on the engineering stack exchange can give you some formulas if you want to do the math.

Comment: Can you tell me approximately what percentage (like 10-15%) of heat is exchagned by thermal radiation by the glass of milk in a room? I just want an idea of presence of thermal radiation around us.

Comment: Nope, sorry. But there are plenty of others here who know exactly how!